# how can i iterate and subtract two command cursor object like this in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have two collections names batting and candidates. First i do aggregate and necessary pipeline aggregations to get my outputs.

```
batting_data = batting.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$playerID",
                "AB": {"$sum": "$AB"},
                "R": {"$sum": "$R"},
                "H": {"$sum": "$H"},
                "2B": {"$sum": "$2B"},
            },
        },
        {"$match": {"AB": {"$gt": 0}}},
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "avg": {"$divide": ["$H", "$AB"]},
                "slug": {
                    "$divide": [
                        {
                            "$add": [
                                "$H",
                                "$2B",
                                {"$multiply": ["$HR", 3]},
                            ]
                        },
                        "$AB",
                    ]
                },
            }
        },
    ]
)
```

And second collections names candidates.

```
candidates_data = candidates.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$playerID",
                "AB": {"$sum": "$AB"},
                "R": {"$sum": "$R"},
                "H": {"$sum": "$H"},
                "2B": {"$sum": "$2B"},
            },
        },
        {"$match": {"AB": {"$gt": 0}}},
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "avg": {"$divide": ["$H", "$AB"]},
                "slug": {
                    "$divide": [
                        {
                            "$add": [
                                "$H",
                                "$2B",
                                {"$multiply": ["$HR", 3]},
                            ]
                        },
                        "$AB",
                    ]
                },
            }
        },
    ]
)

After that I got two object output like this,
```

```
for i in batting_data:
    print(i)
```

output:

```
{'_id': 'kellyto01', 'AB': 127, 'R': 11, 'H': 23, '2B': 5, 'avg': 0.18110236220472442}
{'_id': 'cedenan01', 'AB': 2051, 'R': 221, 'H': 485, '2B': 98, 'avg': 0.23647001462701123}
{'_id': 'fanokha01', 'AB': 6, 'R': 0, 'H': 2, '2B': 1, 'avg': 0.333333333333333}
{'_id': 'baueral01', 'AB': 23, 'R': 3, 'H': 5, '2B': 0, 'avg': 0.21739130434782608}
{'_id': 'coleal01', 'AB': 1760, 'R': 286, 'H': 493, '2B': 58, 'avg': 0.28011363636363634}
{'_id': 'cuylemi01', 'AB': 1386, 'R': 227, 'H': 329, '2B': 47, 'avg': 0.23737373737373738}
{'_id': 'dicksla01', 'AB': 3, 'R': 0, 'H': 0, '2B': 0, 'avg': 0.0}
{'_id': 'willijo01', 'AB': 48, 'R': 2, 'H': 6, '2B': 1, 'avg': 0.12}
{'_id': 'deshide01', 'AB': 5779, 'R': 872, 'H': 1548, '2B': 244, 'avg': 0.2678664128741997}
{'_id': 'mooretr01', 'AB': 26, 'R': 1, 'H': 6, '2B': 2, 'avg': 0.23076923076923078}
{'_id': 'smythha01', 'AB': 54, 'R': 7, 'H': 13, '2B': 2, 'avg': 0.24074074074074073}
{'_id': 'garceri01', 'AB': 3, 'R': 0, 'H': 0, '2B': 0, 'avg': 0.0}
{'_id': 'gardimi01', 'AB': 4, 'R': 0, 'H': 0, '2B': 0, 'avg': 0.0}
{'_id': 'calhowi01', 'AB': 542, 'R': 65, 'H': 133, '2B': 21, 'avg': 0.24538745387453875,}
```

And for candidates_data :

```
for i in candidates_data:
    print(i)
```

```
{'_id': 'bondsba01', 'AB': 9847, 'R': 2227, 'H': 2935, '2B': 601, 'avg': 0.29806032294099727}
{'_id': 'brookhu01', 'AB': 5974, 'R': 656, 'H': 1608, '2B': 290, 'avg': 0.26916638767994644}
{'_id': 'jamesbo01', 'AB': 21, 'R': 0, 'H': 4, '2B': 0, 'avg': 0.19047619047619047}
{'_id': 'hassero01', 'AB': 3440, 'R': 348, 'H': 914, '2B': 172, 'avg': 0.26569767441860465}
{'_id': 'addybo01', 'AB': 1231, 'R': 227, 'H': 341, '2B': 36, 'avg': 0.2770105605199025}
{'_id': 'cedence01', 'AB': 7310, 'R': 1084, 'H': 2087, '2B': 436, 'avg': 0.28549931600547196}
```

Now i am trying to execute the code like,

```
score = 0.0
for can in candidates_data:
    for bat in batting_data:
        score = 1000 - (((can['AB'] - bat['AB'])/20) + ((can['H'] - bat['H'])/25))
```

And it should print every line that inside the candidate output. So thats i am trying to loop candidates first and then batting data in inner loop.

My Output expectation like,

```
bondsba01 - 568.56
brookhu01 - 450.67

like this upto the loop is running
```

If anyone response . It would be a great help . Thanks,

Comment: What is the relationship between the two collections? Have looked at the possibility of using the `$lookup` aggregation stage?

Comment: But lookup takes longer time to run. Because my datasets are large. So, is there any alternative solution.